# Inference in the solution of an indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Adult learner working though a chapter on the applications of basic integration, specifically the calculation of the area between two lines, and the solutions manual states that as part of the solution $\int{\cos(\pi x)}\ dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\sin{\pi x}\ (+ C)$.

I realize that $\int \cos x = \sin x + C$, but I can understand why the above is true.  What rule is at play here?

If I were to try and differentiate $\sin(\pi x)$, I believe I would have to use the chain rule, such that $\frac{d}{dx} \sin(\pi x) = \pi\cos(\pi x)$, but I thought the substitution rule was the inverse of the chain rule for the purposes of integration, and I can't work out how the substitution would have been implicitly performed in the above inference (i.e. equation).

Comment: The substitution is $u=\pi x$, and then the factor of $1/\pi$ comes in sorting out the "$du$".

Comment: Oh! Of course. I feel so sheepish. Thanks @Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do the substitution $x=\frac1\pi y$ and $\mathrm dx=\frac1\pi\,\mathrm dy$, then $\int\cos(\pi x)\,\mathrm dx$ becomes $\frac1\pi\int\cos(y)\,\mathrm dy$, which is $\frac1\pi\sin(y)$ plus a constant. But $\frac1\pi\sin(y)=\frac1\pi\sin(\pi x)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you write out the steps explicitly, you have

> Let $u = \pi x$, then $ \operatorname{d}\!u = \pi \operatorname{d}\!x$, and thus
> \begin{align}
>  \int \cos (\pi x) \operatorname{d}\!x & = \frac1\pi\int \cos (\pi x) \underbrace{\pi\operatorname{d}\!x}_{\operatorname{d}\!u} \\
> & = \frac1\pi\int \cos (u) \operatorname{d}\!u & \text{(Integration by Substitution)} \\
> &= \frac1\pi \sin (u) + C \\
> &= \frac1\pi \sin(\pi x) + C.  & (u = \pi x)
> \end{align}

See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) for more information on how to use integration by substitution.

Comment: Thanks for the really drawn out solution. I feel silly not having actually tried to perform the substitution rule. I got confused by the other terms of the expression that didn't require it.

Comment: I also want to give a remark on your interpretation of integration by substitution. In the link I have given above, it also stated a version where you can substitute the derivative as if you are applying chain rule backwards. That rule coincides with your interpretation, and is actually a consequence of the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the full sense of the first part of the fundamental theorem of calculus. I'm hoping continued practice and reflection will inspire the muses to bestow a eureka moment.